# How can I sort a List by megapixel and then by name?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.7.2

Some time ago, I wrote a program in VB.Net which is similar to the familiar Windows image viewer but has a few more advantages. Today I would like to develop the program further, with the addition that one can also sort according to image dimensions (i.e. megapixels), and the images are displayed in this order (descending).
So my concern to you is: *How can I sort by megapixel and then by name? I'm not that good with lists and the sorting commands for them yet.*
I've written a separate class called "Image Properties". Here, for each image, the complete path and the dimensions are transferred and the megapixels are calculated.

**Code in Form_Main**

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class Form_Main
    Private Shared Form2 As Form_Anzeige
    ''' <summary>
    ''' List with file names
    ''' </summary>
    Public Liste_mit_Dateinamen As List(Of String)
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    ''' <summary>
    ''' List with instances of the class Bildeigenschaften (image properties)
    ''' </summary>
    Private Liste_Klasse_Bildeigenschaften As New List(Of Bildeigenschaften)
    Private Sub Form_Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Screens As Screen() = Screen.AllScreens
        If Screens.Length = 1 AndAlso (Screens(0).Bounds.Width < 1920 OrElse Screens(0).Bounds.Height < 1080) Then
            MessageBox.Show($"Es wurde kein zweiter Bildschirm angeschlossen und der erste hat eine zu kleine Auflösung{Environment.NewLine}(1920 × 1080 wäre nötig).", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Start.Click
        Dim path_to_folder As String = ""
        Using OFolderD As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFolderD.Title = "Ordner auswählen"
            OFolderD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            OFolderD.IsFolderPicker = True
            If OFolderD.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                path_to_folder = OFolderD.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Dim Liste_FI As New List(Of IO.FileInfo)
        Dim DI As IO.DirectoryInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo(path_to_folder)
        Dim ExtensionList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".png"}

        For Each File As IO.FileInfo In DI.GetFiles
            If ExtensionList.Contains(File.Extension.ToLower(Deu)) Then
                Liste_FI.Add(File)
                Using temp_Bmp As New Bitmap(File.FullName)
                    Liste_Klasse_Bildeigenschaften.Add(New Bildeigenschaften(CUInt(temp_Bmp.Width), CUInt(temp_Bmp.Height), File.Name))
                End Using
            End If
        Next

        If Liste_FI.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("In dem gewählten Ordner befinden sich keine Bilder (jpg, bmp, png).", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Return
        End If

        Liste_mit_Dateinamen = New List(Of String)

        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            Dim query As IEnumerable(Of IO.FileInfo) = Liste_FI.OrderBy(Function(Info As IO.FileInfo) Info.CreationTime)
            For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In query
                Liste_mit_Dateinamen.Add(fi.FullName)
            Next
        End If
        If RadioButton2.Checked Then
            Dim query As IEnumerable(Of IO.FileInfo) = Liste_FI.OrderBy(Function(Info As IO.FileInfo) Info.Name)
            For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In query
                Liste_mit_Dateinamen.Add(fi.FullName)
            Next
        End If
        If RadioButton3.Checked Then
'              here
        End If

        'Nicht-modaler Dialog auf großem Bildschirm (mind. 1920 × 1080). Benutzer soll Form2 nach Belieben (irgendwann) wegklicken.
        'non-modal dialog on large screen (at least 1920 × 1080). User can close Form2 at will (at some point). 
        Form2 = New Form_Anzeige
        If Not Form2.Visible AndAlso Not Form2.IsDisposed AndAlso Liste_mit_Dateinamen.Count > 0 Then
            Form2.Show(Me)
            Button_Start.Enabled = False
        
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Stop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Stop.Click
        If Form2 IsNot Nothing Then
            Form2.Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Code of class „Bildeigenschaften“ (“image properties”)**

```
NotInheritable Class Bildeigenschaften
    Private Megapixels As UInt32
    Private Path_to_the_file As String = ""
    Public Sub New(ByVal _width As UInt32, ByVal _height As UInt32, ByVal _path As String)
        Me.Megapixels = _width * _height
        Me.Path_to_the_file = _path
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.

```vb
Public Class Thing

    Public Property First As String
    Public Property Second As String

End Class
```

```vb
Dim things As New List(Of Thing)

'...

things.Sort(Function(t1, t2)
                Dim result = t1.First.CompareTo(t2.First)

                If result = 0 Then
                    result = t1.Second.CompareTo(t2.Second)
                End If

                Return result
            End Function)
```

That code uses the [`List(Of T).Sort(Comparison(Of T))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) method. There are other specific ways to sort but they all rely on a similar principle, i.e. repeated comparison of pairs of items to produce an `Integer` value that represents their relative magnitude. In such comparisons, a value less than zero means that the first item is less than the first, a value greater than zero means that the second item is less than the first item and zero means they are equal. That is why, in this code, the second property is compared if and only if comparison of the first property produces a result of zero.

For more information on comparing and sorting methods, see my blog post [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html). Note that there are three parts to that post.

Comment: Thank you for the general example, really, I'll print that out. Everything works.